# How to tranfer data from fragment to activity in Android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

Here is my code:-

```
class ACFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val id = "ac"

        fb_ac.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@ACFragment, AddFunction::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("id", id)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ac, container, false)
    }
}
```

I want to transfer data from fragment to activity using Intent but I am unable to do it. Can Someone please help me?

Comment: what exactly is the problem you're having ? what isn't working ?

Comment: Are you trying to transfer info to the Activity that already contains this fragment? If you’re trying to pass data to a new activity, you’re already doing it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the `id` string in the `AddFunction` activity by calling the `getStringExtra` method:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    ...

    val id = intent.getStringExtra("id") ?: ""
}
```

Also, you should change your `onCreateView` declaration like this:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ac, container, false)

    val id = "ac"

    view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.fb_ac).setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(requireContext(), AddFunction::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("id", id)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    return view 
}
```